# No.of Users in Socket.io Namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there any built-in way to find out number of users connected to a particular namespace in Node.js server that uses Socket.io?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be better ways but this should work :

```
Object.keys(io.of('/chat').manager.handshaken).length       //handshaken clients
Object.keys(io.of('/chat').manager.connected).length        //connected clients
Object.keys(io.of('/chat').manager.open).length             //open clients
Object.keys(io.of('/chat').manager.closed).length           //closed clients
```

You can replace `/chat` with your namespace. Namespace must start with a `/`. These are objects in the socket.io object `io` which store connected users (do `console.log(io.of('/chat').manager.connected)` to see the object).

#### Update

The easier way `io.of('/chat').clients().length`. See `io.of('/chat').clients()` to get all connected user details.